# Reading commands from text file for batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to use a .bat file to read lines from .txt file then use them as commands. The text file is updated everyday so the size or the number of lines is unknown. I seem to be stuck on it. I'm completely new to batch scripting. So any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the lines of a file with

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foo.txt) do ...
```

To use whatever is *in* those lines as commands, just execute it:

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foo.txt) do %%L
```

A simpler way might be to just rename the file to a batch file and run it:

```
ren foo.txt foo.cmd
call foo.cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is this:

```
cmd < foo.txt
```

This method also allows you to include lines of input data for commands in the lines following the commands. For example, try previous line with this foo.txt file:

```
echo Read the value given in next line
set /P var=
This is the value
echo The value read is: %var%
```

This feature may ve very useful in certain cases.

Comment: Ooh, nice. I didn't think of that so far. And as usual, it's a tradeoff, in that you cannot use batch file constructs. But the option to include interactive input is nice.